# default null, но значение notNULL. Структура таблиц, значение по умолчанию

Tags: mysql, sql, null

вопрос возник из комментов отсюда [подсчет количества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609385/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0). 
[image: коменты]

Есть такие таблички

```
mysql> describe usopt;
  +---------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------------------------------------+
  | Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default                                  |
  +---------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------------------------------------+
  | uid_usopt     | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL                                     |
  | usname        | varchar(25)         | NO   |     | NULL                                     |
  | skinid_usopt  | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | 1                                        |


mysql> describe skin;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| skinid       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| skin_name    | varchar(32)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| uid_skinfrom | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| skin_way     | varchar(32)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_skin    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
```

Обратите внимание на то что у

```
  +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
  | Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
  +--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | skinid        | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 | uid_usopt     | int(10) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL                                     |
```

---

```
 | usname        | varchar(25)         | NO   |     | NULL
```

У меня по умолчанию NULL в тех полях где значение не может быть NULL
Зачем такая бредовая структура таблиц? Ответ очень прост: Для того чтобы при попытке вставки пустого значения (например значения пустой переменной) в таблицу, вставка не происходила и получалась ошибка. Разумеется что перед вставкой в таблицы в php кода всегда есть валидация данныз, но вдруг случайно или не случайно что-то пойдет не так?

Я задавал значения NOT NULL. NULL по умолчания я специально НЕ ставил. Это субд, которой  я пользуюсь, ставит NULL.

Кстати я к этому случайно додумался ранее (летом2016), когда задавал тут вопросы.

Не все то что кажется на первый взгляд абсолютным бредом, является таковым.

ВНИМАНИЕ! вопрос: Правильно ли я сделал? Я считаю что это действительно сильно! Или нет?

Comment: NULL в колонке defult лишь отображает, что значение по умолчанию для колонки не задано

Comment: у меня при попытке вставки null значения, вставка не происходила. Потому что если значение переменной NULL и оно вставляется в поле которое не должно быть NULL, получается ошибка. Или я не прав ИЛИ нужно еще раз протестировать. Ну а то что у меня в PRI notNULL и default NULL - то это уже некорректно(?)

Comment: default NULL - значит что значение по умолчанию _не определено_, а раз оно _не определено_ то если при вставке в таблицу данное поле не заполнять то в него попытается записаться NULL и да, будет ошибка вставки. И это нормальное поведение. Должна же СУБД как то отреагировать на то что забыли задать значение для обязательного поля

Comment: Вы не обращайте внимания на тот комментарий Akina, он просто не разобрался, что desribe так отображает структуру таблицы. Конечно более красиво было бы, если бы он показал просто пустую ячейку таблицы в этом месте, а не NULL. Но он (desribe) работает как работает.

Comment: ну "показ пустой строки" может сдержать пробел. Я понял. Внимание я стараюсь обращать на всё. Мне очень помогает и этот ресурс и другие. Хотя в последнее время я только тут спрашиваю +гуголь помогает.

Comment: Ну я бы на их месте пробел бы отображал в кавычках, но сильно сомневаюсь, что они так делают. Я думаю вы в этой табличке не отличите default = пробел от двух пробелов например :)

Comment: "если при вставке в таблицу данное поле не заполнять то в него попытается записаться NULL и да, будет ошибка вставки. И это нормальное поведение." - ну и я о том же. Это в т ч спасает при отладке.

Answer (score 1):

Речь идет о разных, на прямую между собой не связанных вещах. Если было указано, что колонка NOT NULL, никто же не мешает задать значение по умолчанию. Если оно не указано, то значение по умолчанию - NULL. Для уникальных ключей смысла устанавливать значение по умолчанию, понятно, смысла нет.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1062371/217579). Делать столбец NOT NULL и ставить значение по умолчанию не всегда целесообразно.

Как здесь:

```
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------------------------------------+
| Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default                                  |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+------------------------------------------+
| skinid_usopt  | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | 1
```

Если по этому столбцу будет поиск, то лучше сделать его `NULLABLE` и создать по нему индекс. В индексе значения `NULL` не сохраняются, поэтому он будет небольшим и эффективным.